# How to check from Java API if specific DynamoDB index exists

Tags: java, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

What is the proper way to check from Java API if index with specific name exists in DynamoDB table?

According to javadoc to Table and Index classes I couldn't find any appropriate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the DynamoDB [`Table`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Table.html) class from the [Document API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIItemCRUD.html), you would use the [`describe()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Table.html#describe()) method to get the [`TableDescription`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/TableDescription.html). You can then use the [`getGlobalSecondaryIndexes()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/TableDescription.html#getGlobalSecondaryIndexes()) or the [`getLocalSecondaryIndexes()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/TableDescription.html#getLocalSecondaryIndexes()) depending on which indexes you are interested in.

If you are using the [`AmazonDynamoDBClient`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html), you can essentially do the same thing with [`describeTable(String tableName)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html#describeTable(java.lang.String)). In this case you are returned a [`DescribeTableResult`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/DescribeTableResult.html) with which you can get the [`TableDescription`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/DescribeTableResult.html#getTable()) as mentioned above.

These operations all boil down to calling [*DescribeTable*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index info from databasemetadata.

ResultSet   getIndexInfo(String catalog, String schema, String table, boolean unique, boolean approximate)
Retrieves a description of the given table's indices and statistics.

Here is the link

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html

Comment: DynamoDB is not a SQL database... This answer does not apply here.